# Writing a Long from Java in a file and reading it in C++

Tags: java, c++, long-integer

I want to create a file that contains exactly 8 bytes representing an unsigned long number. The file is created with Java and then read by C++. This is how Java creates the file:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Writer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
        buffer.putLong(12345);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stream.write(buffer.array());
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("myFile")) {
            outputStream.write(stream.toByteArray());
        }

    }

}
```

And this is how C++ reads it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

// I use this to get each byte from a file
static std::vector<char> ReadAllBytes(char const* filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, ios::binary|ios::ate);
    std::ifstream::pos_type pos = ifs.tellg();

    std::vector<char>  result(pos);

    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    ifs.read(&result[0], pos);

    return result;
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<char> bytes = ReadAllBytes("myFile");
    std::vector<char>::iterator it = bytes.begin();

    char longBytes[8];
    std::copy(&(*it), &(*it) + 8, longBytes);
    unsigned long value = *((unsigned long*)longBytes);

    std::cout << "Size: " << value;
}
```

The expected output is `12345`, but instead I get `4120793659044003840`.

I am not sure if I did it wrong in Java or C++. Or both. What should I have done?

Comment: Why use the iterators for copying? Why not using e.g. `&bytes[0]`? And why use the character array and the casting, instead of copying directly into `value`? And you should be careful with assuming that `long` is a 64-bit type, it's not guaranteed, and the Visual Studio compiler still have `long` as a 32-bit type even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg because this is a fragment of a larger and more complex program. The program was not working and I pinpointed it to this code in particular.

Comment: Nayuki Minase is absolutely correct.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) If you're troubleshooting binary, then look at the hex values: 12345 =` 0x00003039`, 4120793659044003840=`0x3930000000000000`.  2) If you can avoid reading and writing binary, then do it.  Text (XML, JSON or just a text "flat file") is almost always preferable to binary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java writes `long` in "network order", which is big endian. C++ reads in hardware order, which in your case is little endian.

It does not mean, however, that your C++ program should flip the bytes for conversion, because in this case it would fail on hardware with big endian order.

C provides a special group of functions for platform-independent conversion of data to and from network order. You need to use [`htonll`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36875/ntohll-3socket.html) function, which converts eight bytes in network order to your hardware order.

Comment: So this is a problem that cannot be solved from the Java side, right?

Comment: @Voldemort Java is the side which has solved its side of the problem by ensuring that the data is written in the same order on all platforms. It's C/C++ side where you are given the flexibility to choose the order yourself.

Comment: Is `htonll` guaranteed to operate on 64-bit values?  Wouldn't something like `be64toh()` be better as I'd think `uint64_t` would be better than `unsigned long` in this case.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `ntohll` and `htonll` are defined in terms of `uint64_t`, so you are absolutely right, using these platform-independent types would be the right choice here.

Comment: @Voldemort - When transferring raw binary data - especially integral types - endianness **always** needs to be specified.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Are they *defined* in terms of `uint64_t` by some standard, or just normally *implemented* that way by convention?  I don't recall a standard, and I can't seem to find one that applies at the moment.

Comment: Which *standard* version of C or C++ contain the `htonll` functions, since you claim they are provided by the C language?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You took the "C provides" part of my answer too literally. Since `ntohll` is part of the common "ecosystem" of libraries built around C, with nearly universal availability, I do not see a need for a lengthy disclaimer explaining that the function is not part of a C standard.

Answer (score 7):

Java writes the `long` as bytes encoded in big endian, guaranteed.

C++ reads the bytes, and on your machine (assumed to be Intel x86) they are interpreted in little endian as an integer. (Big endian on Motorola 68k and others.)

One solution to your problem is to manually reconstruct the integer in C++ in a portable way:

```
uint64_t value =
    (uint64_t)(b[0] & 0xFF) << 56 |
    (uint64_t)(b[1] & 0xFF) << 48 |
    (uint64_t)(b[2] & 0xFF) << 40 |
    (uint64_t)(b[3] & 0xFF) << 32 |
    (uint64_t)(b[4] & 0xFF) << 24 |
    (uint64_t)(b[5] & 0xFF) << 16 |
    (uint64_t)(b[6] & 0xFF) <<  8 |
    (uint64_t)(b[7] & 0xFF) <<  0;
```

---

Side note: Your Java code can be simplified:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myFile"));
try {
    out.writeLong(12345);  // 8 bytes in big endian
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: So in Java I should flip the written bytes? Probably with `buffer.flip()`? I'll try that.

Comment: You can flip the endianness in either Java or C++. Pick the alternative that you think makes the most sense conceptually.

Comment: Strange... it seems to output the same number (I used `buffer.flip()`)

Comment: Read the documentation for ByteBuffer.flip()... it doesn't do what you assumed it does.